# Table Select one column and divide into two different

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table like this let's call it action:

```
id | amt | time_stamp | act_id |
---+-----+------------+--------+
int| int | timestamp  | int    |
```

and another table (let's call it action_type):

```
id | name
---+-----
int| str
```

in which (and this is important) are two entries: **give** and **take**  
Now what i need to do is create select statement
where at the end i'll have result like this:

```
sum_give | sum_take | time_stamp |
---------+----------+------------+
```

where sum give is

```
select 
sum(amt) as sum_give,
cast (date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) as timestamp) as hr
from action
where act_id=1
group_by date_trunc('hour' ...);
```

and the other is

```
select 
sum(amt) as sum_take,
cast (date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) as timestamp) as hr
from action
where act_id=2
...
```

you get the picture...
I don't know how to create the result i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(amt) FILTER (WHERE act_id = 1) AS sum_give,
    SUM(amt) FILTER (WHERE act_id = 2) AS sum_take,
    CAST(DATE_TRUNC('hour', time_stamp) AS timestamp) AS hr
FROM action
GROUP BY 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply need a CASE statement -

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN act_id=1 THEN amt END) as sum_give,
       sum(CASE WHEN act_id=2 THEN amt END) as sum_take,
       cast (date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) as timestamp) as hr
  FROM action
 WHERE act_id IN (1, 2)
 GROUP BY date_trunc('hour' ...);
```